# Need some help in understanding this Google Sheets arrayformula function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The function is:

`=arrayformula( (NORMINV(RANDarray(1,4000),$K3,$L3) * AVERAGE($G3,1)) * $J3 )`

My understanding is that this creates a list of 4000 random values and for each random value, it passes that value to the `NORMINV` function along with the fixed values in the cells `K3` and `L3` as parameters. The return value of this function is then multiplied with the average of the value in the cell `G3` and the number 1 and this in turn is multiplied by the value in the cell `J3`. Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 2):

yes, that is correct. RANDARRAY will generate a row with 4000 columns with random numbers between 0 and 1. this array is then used in NORMINV and multiplied by AVERAGE between G3 and 1 and then multiplied again with J3